# Search users in organization using Github Rest API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to search for users in a Github organization using the rest API.

I found the [members list](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#members-list) query that doesn't allow searching, and I found the [user search](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users) query that apparently doesn't allow filtering by organization.

I basically want something in between these two queries but couldn't find it.

Is there another way to do it that I am missing?

Comment: I think you can filter users in organization, did you check the documentation https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/

Comment: Yeah, and the fields there don't let you filter by name. only by role and type